# Решение проблемы флагов в чате: устранение неверной интерпретации правил

Tags: обсуждение, тревоги, чат

В последнее время в [чате Ru.SO](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) наблюдается волна «флагов» — тревог типа «спам или оскорбление» на сообщения. Однако данными тревогами были помечены и те сообщения, которые являются исходно нейтральными.

В результате выяснилось, что причиной флагов *могло отчасти (UPD: см. комментарии)*  являться достаточно размытое описание того, о чем в чате писать нельзя. В частности, в краткой справке по использованию чата написано следующее:

[image: Chat short help on login]

Второй пункт был переведён примерно следующим образом:

> Видите что-то, что вас смущает? Флагайте без колебаний.

Получается, что первое предложение поощряет флагание *всего*, что вызывает *смущение* (априори слабую и мимолётную эмоцию), а второе — призывает делать это без промедления (то есть без предварительного анализа).

UPD: в комментариях **поступило дополнение** от @NicolasChabanovsky: *«do not hesitate» – не стесняйтесь, это не призыв. В случае дословного перевода, который я никогда бы не использовал, фраза бы была такой «Если вы испытываете дискомфорт, не стесняйтесь использовать тревогу». Пожалуйста, учтите вот этот вот «дискомфорт», куда ближе к «Facepalm», нежели когда ботинки жмут.*

И, как результат, данное «правило» поощряет флагать всё, что *хоть как-то* вам не понравилось?

**Я считаю, что это в корне неверно!**

Из-за невнимательности исходная фраза «make uneasy» (причинять беспокойство) [была заменена](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41314473#41314473) на «feel uneasy» (смущаться). Причём дальнейшем никто не обратил внимание на это подмену.

Хорошо, допустим. Но даже в этом случае Google Translate утверждает, что «make uneasy» — «беспокоиться», что ничуть не меняет смысл правила. Вероятно, это и стало причиной вышеуказанного искажения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Однако Collins Dictionary [считает совершенно иначе](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/uneasy):**

> Если вы *«uneasy»*, значит, вы испытываете озабоченность (*альт.* беспокойство), страх из-за мысли, что сделали что-то неправильно, или из-за чувства опасности.
>
> ---
>
> If you are uneasy, you feel anxious, afraid, or embarrassed, because you think that something is wrong or that there is danger.

Да, ниже есть американо-английское определение, похожее по смыслу на *feel uneasy*, однако, общее определение более строгое, а потому именно его могли иметь в виду авторы краткого руководства.

Получаем, что невинный намёк на дискомфорт, в состояние которого войти и выйти проще некуда, оказывается относительно серьёзным ощущением, присущим грубейшим оскорблениям, преследованию и травле. Это, кстати, обосновывает и глобальность флагов, рассылаемых по всей сети StackOverflow: подобные серьёзные вещи универсальны и не зависят от культуры и контекста применения.

Прибавляем к этому ещё и название соответствующего пункта меню: *Flag as spam/offensive*, то есть спам (реклама без раскрытия причастности автора сообщения — из списка тревог на основном сайте) и оскорбления/агрессию.

**Таким образом**, флаги должны применяться **только при достаточно серьёзных вещах** (спам, оскорбления, агрессия и травля) и никак иначе.

Comment: Исходная фраза это "something that makes you uneasy", не надо подменять её на "make uneasy" и пытаться переводить это.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исключите из вопроса «В результате выяснилось, что причиной флагов является достаточно размытое описание того, о чем в чате писать нельзя.» Причиной является призывы к их неверному использованию. «do not hesitate» – не стесняйтесь, это не призыв. В случае дословного перевода, который я никогда бы не использовал, фраза бы была такой «Если вы испытываете дискомфорт, не стесняйтесь использовать тревогу». Пожалуйста, учтите вот этот вот «дискомфорт», куда ближе к «[Facepalm](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facepalm)», нежели когда ботинки жмут.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие действия вы ожидаете с моей стороны?

Answer (score 5):

Есть вопрос ["A guide to moderating chat"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271267/152799), где "chat" это chat.stackexchange.com, в т.ч. и наша комната.

Там написано:

> **Remember: Only flag things that are truly inappropriate or offensive.**
>
> When you flag a message, you draw the attention of every mod and 10 k user currently on the chat network. This means you should only be flagging things that they’re going to see as offensive as well, which includes:
>
> - Personal attacks (characterized by you, e.g., “You’re a moron.”)
> - Anything that [shocks the conscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocks_the_conscience) (yes, this is subjective — let your conscience be your guide.)

При этом "[shocks the conscience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shocks_the_conscience)" это термин юриспруденции США и Канады:

> An action is understood to "shock the conscience" if it is perceived as manifestly and grossly unjust, typically by a judge.
>
> (мой перевод) Действие считается ["шокирующим сознание"](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=shock+the+conscience) если оно выглядит [явно неправомерным](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=manifestly%20unjust) и [глубоко несправедливым](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=grossly%20unjust), обычно с точки зрения судьи.

Если правила меты мет распространяются на нас, то флагать можно только сообщения подпадающие под описанное выше.

Comment: В английском варианте написано "... включая Personal attacks и shocks the conscience". Вы перевели это как "только Personal attacks и shocks the conscience".

Comment: ну и логичный вывод - на англоязычных сообщениях в англоязычных чатах флаги тоже ставить нельзя, т.к. многие пользователи с 10k репутации из ruSO, jpSO, ptSO вообще не понимают, что там по английски написано. Правила же у нас общие для всех? Значит флаги запрещены на любом языке (если использовать вашу трактовку правил).

Comment: @PashaPash о чем Вы вообще? У меня в ответе перевод - только там где написано "(мой перевод)". Остальное  - либо прямые цитаты, либо вывод "флагать можно только сообщения подпадающие под описанное выше [текст с meta.SE]". У этого вывода не написано "перевод", не надо выдумывать.

Comment: **я отвечал на ваш удаленный комментарий** "you should only be flagging things that they [10 users] [a]re going to see as offensive as well" - означает что у нас вообще ничего не надо флагать, т.к. зарубежные 10к юзеры вообще не понимают что мы пишем по русски.". Несколько странно сначала удалить комментарий, на который я вам ответил, а потом удивляться "о чем вы вообще".

Comment: @PashaPash, да, я перечитал Ваш первый комментарий и подумал что Вы написали что-то странное - какое еще "Вы перевели"?

Comment: ну раз ваш ответ не несет никакой дополнительной ценности, не является переводом, и просто сводится к краткой цитате на английском из развернутого ответа на мете MSE - может быть стоило бы ограничится ссылкой?

Comment: @PashaPash там есть кнопка "удалить". Ссылку тоже можете написать сами. Или "преобразовать в комментарий". Как хотите.