# Кризис флагов в чате

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, чат

Не так давно сняли владельцев чата и уже с неделю сообщество находится в состоянии кризиса:

> Кри́зис — состояние, при котором существующие средства достижения
>   целей становятся неадекватными, в результате чего возникают
>   непредсказуемые ситуации.
>
> Кризис проявляет скрытые конфликты и диспропорции.

В подтверждение процитирую [мнение](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42287222#42287222), которое полностью разделяю:

> Думаю, эта неделя попросту стала кульминацией того снежного кома, что
>   копился месяцами из-за сначала неверного понимания интерфейса
>   модерации чата, а потом просто взаимной ненависти и мстительного ража.

Я бы хотел сформулировать и озвучить те скрытые конфликты, которые я вижу и которые необходимо решить. На истину не претендую, поэтому если кто готов подискутировать – вэлком в ответы и комментарии.

---

В первую очередь я вижу, что на уровне управляющей компании stackoverflow отсутствует единое понимание, как должна работать система флагов. В одних официальных источниках (справка, MSE) содержатся одни рекомендации, в других – другие. Подробнее – в [посте @Abyx](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6723/213987).

Запутывает ситуацию и то, что разные чиновники имеют разную личную трактовку правил, в разное время давали высказывания, которые можно то трактовать по-разному. (Можно я не буду из этических соображений приводить ссылки на чат? Тем более их искать сложно)

И совсем подливает масла в огонь позиция высокореповых участников сети SE, которых система случайным образом привлекает на тревоги в русском чате. Даже если принять, что флаги разрешены – эти участники негативят, особенно с учётом того, что они не все понимают русский язык.

Как можно решить это противоречие? Я думаю, нужна чёткая и недвусмысленная формулировка утверждённая на самом высоком уровне и аккуратно доведённая до русского сообщества (без потерь на перевод). Чтобы мы могли с некоторой даты привести эту норму как обязательную и могли сослаться на её текст в русском и английском варианте.

---

Второе противоречие глобально и вряд ли мы его сможем решить. С одной стороны русскоязычное сообщество большая и важная часть SE, с другой стороны — мы там никому не нужны и проблемы не-англоязычных сообществ заброшены и не исправляются. Давайте что ли я попробую привести более конкретные вещи, которые вытекают из этого противоречия – они выглядят как более решаемые.

С 2015 года существует проблема, что [флаги обрабатываются без учёта локализации](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258676/348096). Флаг на сообщение в русскоязычном чате может быть показан пользователю, который знает только английский язык.

От этого возникают проблемы с тем, что пользователи не знающие русский язык делают ревью флага наугад. (Возможно, что это миф – могу сослаться на Николаса, который считал такие случаи)

Этот вопрос с тем, чтобы оставить решение флагов только пользователям, кто хорошо знает язык важен вот ещё с какой стороны. Компания-владелец stackoverflow на правах владельца (so - частная территория) имеет право устанавливать любые правила. Тем не менее, часть участников чата хотела бы, чтобы в русскоязычных чатах были приняты не правила англосаксонской культуры, а были учтены местные / локальные культурные особенности и традиции русского сообщества.

Этот конфликт возможно мифический, возможно виртуальный — но весьма острый. Подобного рода конфликт (компания H & M) довёл до реальных погромов, в нашем случае мы можем говорить о протестах и потенциальном уходе части участников из чата и сайта (эксперты в решении вопросов – важный капитал сообщества).

---

Третье противоречие я вижу в том, что несмотря на то, что все мы разделяем ценности дружественного общения и понимаем необходимость чётких правил поведения, у нас есть достаточно серьёзные разногласия.

В частности, СМ сообщества (не уверен, личная ли это его точка зрения или официальная позиция so) [полагает](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42238184#42238184), что правила должны быть таковы, чтобы не обидеть самого обидчивого:

> Моя позиция: чтобы уместиться в одном чате всем, чтобы каждый мог
>   считать себя его частью, чтобы каждый мог уважительно относится ко
>   всем его участникам, я бы сказал, что надо научиться не обижать самого
>   обидчивого.

Мне это напоминает джайнизм:

> Джайнисты строгие вегетарианцы. Монахи надевают повязки на рот, чтобы
>   не вдохнуть какое-нибудь насекомое, и метут перед собой метелками,
>   чтобы кого-нибудь не раздавить. У джайнизма много общего с буддизмом.

Собственно, на [толерантном Западе борьба за политкорректность дошла именно до такого абсурда](http://polit.ru/article/2018/01/09/google/):

> Изначально идея политкорректности в широком смысле
>   слова заключалась в том, что меньшинства имеют равные права с
>   большинством. А потом она плавно трансформировалась в идею о том, что
>   права меньшинств превалируют над правами большинства. То есть так
>   ненавязчиво и постепенно идея достаточно здравая и разумная была
>   извращена.

Если мы будем ориентироваться на мнение самых обидчивых, не понимающих шутки – то мы должны будем добровольно стать на ступеньку самого глупого, иссушить своё общение (у нас весьма интеллектуальный состав... был) под угрозой флагов и банов.

Лично я этого не хочу и понимаю тех, кто [также](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42286953#42286953) не хочет.

Правила должны быть, но должны быть разумными и адекватными. Не нужно запрещать n-слово: если в англосаксонской культуре это нехорошо, то в нашей культуре такого нет. Смешно запрещать н-слово и банить, если у нас в чате до сих пор ни одного негра не было. Это равнение на "самого обидчивого" является вредным и ненужным.

---

Четвёртое противоречие я вижу в запутанном интерфейсе флагов. Мы уже видели, что даже русскоязычные пользователи, достаточно интеллектуальные постоянно выбирали прямо противоположный вариант ответа при проверке флага.

И это до сих пор не починено и подливает масла в огонь мифов и обид.

---

Вроде бы это всё. У меня непростая неделя, переезд, поэтому если окажется, что какой-то момент упустил – допишу в пост, постараясь не делать большого числа правок "в режиме чата".

Comment: "*Запутывает ситуацию и то, что разные чиновники имеют разную личную трактовку правил.*" Чиновники?

Comment: В чем вопрос-то? Или что именно предлагается обсудить?

Comment: @Abyx вероятно в том, как разрешить существующий кризис. И можно ли это сделать вообще в обозримом будущем без перехода на альтернативную платформу для чата. Кстати, я так и не понял, почему было удалено [сообщение об этом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6746/176217).

Comment: IMO, текущий "кризис" вызван не какими-то абстрактными попытками CM навязать джайнизм. Он вызван отношением "что не оскорбляет меня - не оскорбляет никого" со стороны владельцев комнаты (что закончилось расисткими шутками, причем в сторону **присутствующего в чате участника**, а не в сторону каких-то абстрактных "потенциальных оскорбляемых"). В правилах есть прямой запрет на расизм (и сексизм, кстати). Запрет довольно четкий и ему далеко до идеалов джайнизма.

Comment: Ну и да, подлили масла в огонь пару участников, которые активно ставили "оскорбительный" *на все подряд*, просто чтобы показать проблемы системы флагов. При этом заявляя в соседнем посте на мете "никаких оскорблений в чате у нас нет". Отлично видно, что ситуация "каждый день набегают иностранцы" создана искусственно. Да, в системе флагов есть дырки. Но регулярно расставлять флаги забавы ради, чтобы посмотреть как в чат придет куча непричастных людей - это достаточно странное развлечение. Дергали собаку за хвост. Додергались.

Comment: я к тому, что вы описываете ситуацию как "злая администрация требует беречь мушек и птичек, а мы не могем не оскорблять совсем-совсем обидчивых!", а на практике творилось "давайте по фану тыкать флаги, смотреть как удивленные иностранцы бегают по чату, а потом, при виде товарища из бразилии, пошутим про индейцев и португальцев". Да, аналогия с H&M уместна, но в этом случае в роли авторов каталога оказались пара человек из чата ruSO.

Comment: неужели за ложные флаги в чатах нет санкций?

Comment: @PashaPash откуда Вы вытащили это «не оскорбляет меня — не оскорбляет никого»? Если человек (не важно, овнер, обычный участник или модератор) не считает что-либо оскорбительным на основании чего он может/должен реагировать на это что-то как на оскорбление? Есть система флагов, люди голосуют по ней, ключевого голоса у овнера нет, только у модераторов. Должен ли овнер/модератор соглашаться с каждым поднятым флагом дабы не прослыть основоположником «не оскорбляет меня — не оскорбляет никого» или всё же можно иметь своё мнение?

Comment: @mymedia есть, мы все их сейчас наблюдаем в действии. Уже не первый день, хотя могли бы пресечь на корню, но «не шмогла я, не шмогла».

Comment: @alexolut я понимаю, что ключевого голоса нет. нет, ни модератор, ни овнер не должны соглашаться с каждым флагом. Но при этом над флагами надо *думать, и пытаться посмотреть на флаг с точки зрения того, кто его поставил*, а не сводить обработку флагов к "дайте строгие правила, что считать оскорбительным, а пока правил нет - и оскорблений нет, называем кого хотим и как как хотим". У нас разумные и адекватные правила - "будьте дружелюбными с другими участниками (чата/сайта)". За нарушение дружелюбности - бан аж на пол часа (на сайте, к примеру, всего на 7 дней)

Comment: @alexolut по поводу "не оскорбляет меня" - вот вам конкретная трактовка правил от Abyx. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6743/ -  "флагать можно только сообщения подпадающие под описанное выше". с непонятно откуда взятым словом "только". Это такая же крайность, как "подтверждать все флаги". Крайности - плохо. Жесткие правила (списки нельзя / можно) - тоже. Давайте их избегать.

Comment: @mymedia автоматической системы наказаний за злоупотребление - нет. При этом модераторы не видят кто поставил и кто снял разрезолвленный флаг. Т.е. я не могу зайти, увидеть что злоупотребляет участник ZZZZZ, и принять меры. Увидеть может CM, но только суровыми выборками напрямую из базы. Он пришел, навыбирал, удивился картине - расстановке флагов и решению по ним - и нажал на кнопку, но это заняло некоторое время.

Comment: @PashaPash если мод с ромбом в чате, то в момент появления тревоги ему должно быть видно, кто её инициировал.

Comment: @PashaPash да, я написал "только [...] подпадающие под описанное выше", а выше идут прямые цитаты meta.SE и википедии. Что не так? Где крайность? Соблюдение правил по модерации чата SE, написанных bluefeet - это чтоли крайность? Вы против соблюдения правил написанных модераторами?

Comment: @Abyx а еще вы написали "you should only be flagging things that they [10 users] [a]re going to see as offensive as well" - означает что у нас вообще ничего не надо флагать, т.к. зарубежные 10к юзеры вообще не понимают что мы пишем по русски.". Это - крайность. Это **ваша трактовка правил, которую вы прямо озвучили**. Удалять комментарии с *очень сомнительной трактовкой правил*, а потом удивляться "что не так, что вам непонравилось" - некрасиво.

Comment: @alexolut только в момент появления. после резолва - модераторы не видят ничего, кроме "флаг был". т.е. постоянно висящие участники 10к видят злофлагальщиков и могут принят меры, а непостоянные модераторы - нет.

Comment: @PashaPash я всё еще жду официальных пояснений по поводу того, должны мы соблюдать написанное на meta.SE или нет.

Comment: @Abyx почему вы адресовали этот комментарий мне? я - не "официальное лицо", и не представитель SE. Хоите "официальных пояснений" - обратитесь к официальному представителю компании. Я могу выразить свое личное мнение обычного участника - того, что написано на meta.SE стоит придерживаться, но если есть сомнения по поводу применимости каких-то *договоренностей* с meta.SE на ruSO - стоит прямо спросить это на meta.ruSO. Более того, если вас что-то смущает в текущих договоренностях, принятых на meta.ruSO - их тоже можно пересмотреть. Не всегда удается найти идеальное решение с первой попытки.

Comment: @Abyx кстати, а Вам объяснили причину блокировки в чате? Мне пока не хотят говорить, что хоть на MSE иди за разъяснениями.

Comment: @alexolut, было несколько блокировок, Вы про блокировку после "пора переезжать в другой чат", или после "тут лучше ничего не писать т.к. банят"? Что касается MSE, то я не думаю что это принесет пользу. В худшем случае коллеги-модераторы с MSE нас насовсем забанят, т.к. могут.

Comment: @Abyx не знаю про несколько, я только видел ту, где номинально мне написали про «4 дня». Они еще продолжают тикать.

Comment: @alexolut скорее всего вы получили блокировку по причине [вредоносного шума](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5554/Блокировка-в-чате)

Comment: Клоунада какая-то. Очередная проблема, решение которой половину не устроит.

Comment: @Suvitruf когда Вы там в модераторы страницы Вконтакте собрались?

Comment: По теме обсуждения. Единого отношения к сообщению получившего флаг не будет в любом случае, так что то, что у проверяющих русский не родной язык не проблема.

Comment: "Четвёртое противоречие я вижу в запутанном интерфейсе флагов." мне кажется можно навесить дополнительное сообщение с пояснениями для тех кто использует проверку в первый раз или просто подсказку как это сделано с очередью проверок.

Comment: @alexolut это как-то связано?

Comment: @Suvitruf надеюсь, что нет. Но кризис может случиться, где угодно. Особенно, если Ваша видимость «доброжелательности» разойдется с ожидаемой. В чате вот тоже никто не ждал подвоха до недавнего времени. И я бы еще пару недель назад сам уверял бы Вас, что такого в принципе быть не может. Но оно случилось.

Comment: @FoggyFinder с такой формулировкой можно было всех участвующих в обсуждении забанить, но почему-то затронуло только некоторых. Наверное, сбой в системе.

Comment: @alexolut я просто не совсем ваш посыл понимаю. Кризис случился, да. Проблемы и раньше были, но принятые решения по ним очень многих не удовлетворяли. С текущим кризисом будет тоже самое, по-моему. Особенно, учитывая, что многие предложения в принципе не реализуемы.